# add a common root path before an inner Api with Servant

Tags: haskell, servant

I have the following API :

```
type GSDMonitoringApi =   FetchWorkspaceIdsCreated
                    :<|>  FetchGsdCommandsByWorkspaceId

type FetchWorkspaceIdsCreated =      "gsd" :> "monitoring" :> "workspaceIds" :> Get '[JSON] [Persisted WorkspaceId]
type FetchGsdCommandsByWorkspaceId = "gsd" :> "monitoring" :> "commands" :> Capture "workspaceId" WorkspaceId :> Get '[JSON] [Persisted GsdCommand]
```

is it possible to factor out `"gsd" :> "monitoring" :>` and put it into GSDMonitoringApi only once ?

P.S : Servant is amazingly well done !

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can add the prefix to both branches after combining them:

```
type GSDMonitoringApi = 
    "gsd" :> "monitoring" :> 
    ( FetchWorkspaceIdsCreated :<|> FetchGsdCommandsByWorkspaceId )

type FetchWorkspaceIdsCreated = "workspaceIds" :> Get '[JSON] [Persisted WorkspaceId]
type FetchGsdCommandsByWorkspaceId = "commands" :> Capture "workspaceId" WorkspaceId :> Get '[JSON] [Persisted GsdCommand]
```

As a semi-related point, I recommend that you check out [`Servant.API.Generic`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-12.22/servant-0.14.1/Servant-API-Generic.html). Combining APIs with `:<|>` like that becomes very ugly very quickly. `Servant.API.Generic` solves that to some extent.

Comment: Perhaps reading the cookbook recipe will help make sense of those haddocks (and the corresponding ones in -server, -client, ...): https://haskell-servant.readthedocs.io/en/stable/cookbook/generic/Generic.html